# Ethereum chain data size (GETH w fast sync)

Tags: etherscan, fast-sync, statistics

Etherscan provides [this statistics](https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast), about the chain data size with fast synchronization. I cannot understand if it refers only to the blockchain size (i.e. block headers + block bodies, i.e. transactions) or it includes also the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak to this specific chart but if you fast sync a Geth node the final result does include the state. So, I assume that this chart does include the state. It only includes the most recent state though.